# how to set text of jtable in java swing using eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

I wud like know the way to set the text that is typed in a Jtextfield to the table.Cud anyone help me in it.

Answer (score 3):

Read the value from the textfield and set it in the table’s model.

As my crystal ball is currently being repaired I can not help you without more details.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you are using [jigloo](http://www.cloudgarden.com/jigloo/) or sth similar,it may happen that propertyChange method is not being called and table is not aware of the change,[this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/events/propertychangelistener.html) may help.